What kind of roleplays are Haram in character.ai?
Assalamualaikum my Muslim sisters and brothers. So today I wanted to delete character.ai because I thought it had Haram roleplays. Does it? If so can you name what kind of Haram roleplays I'm not allowed to do in Islam? I saw an answer from this website that said “its an AI. it isn't real, its feeings aren't real, but don't let it distract you from allah.” but I'm still not sure. Is there any Haram roleplays?

it's your phone, your internet and there is no real people. So I think nothing is haraam. Make sure you don't miss any salaat or Islamic duties by using it
